# Php и классы для работы с Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу под свои нужды веб-сайт, код разрастается, переписал его под MVC систему, встал вопрос о добавление класса для более удобной работы с mysql, в данный момент у меня обычный mysqli. Ранее работал с CI и там была удобная штука, active record. Можно ли его "адекватно" имплантировать себе? Или может посоветуете другие классы?

Comment: А почему стали писать собственный велосипед? Использовали бы дальше CI и было бы счастье!

> под MVC систему

MVC - это архитектура приложения

Comment: Ну как сказать, я не планирую делать из него фреймворк. Да и свой код, разрабатывать куда легче, когда знаешь, где и что и как работает + мой веб-сайт полностью на ajax. Т.е роутер уже полностью подготовлен под работу с ajax реквастами и на работу полностью без JavaScript кода(если браузер отключает\неподдерживает). А переписывать CI под эти нужды проблематично, да и в высших кругах CI популярностью не пользуется.

Comment: @avengerweb - [Стоит ли вообще заморачиваться на счет отключенного javascript][1], + к этому - CI прекрасно может отдавать контент в JSON вместо HTML View (это MVC всё таки). 

>Ну как сказать, я не планирую делать из него фреймворк.

Ага, сначала AR, потом ещё куча всего понадобится =) 

[1]: http://goo.gl/iPThTK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Классы](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=active+record&x=0&y=0&go_search=1) для работы с AR, выбирайте какой больше понравится)

Comment: Спасибо, но пока подожду другие варианты или попробую выпилить из CI.

Comment: Помечу как верный, но я перетащил себе с CI класс active record со всеми вытекающими. Пойду подарю плюшку их команде.